# Sql Looping and Concat function in View

Tags: sql, loops, view

IS IT possible to use loops and concat a zero on an ID to its result

Sample

Input

ID no: 1

Result :

ID no: 01

```
CASE 
     WHEN (Schema.TableName.Fieldname > 10 )
            CONCAT(0,Schema.TableName.Fieldname)
     ELSE 
        --IF the Id is already 2 digits
        Select Schema.TableName.Fieldname
END
```

Comment: Which dbms product are you using?

Comment: i am using RDMS i change the code sample

Comment: And what is [RDMS](http://www.acronymfinder.com/RDMS.html) ? ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have in integer column named "ID" and you want to transform it from 1 to 01, 2 to 02 and so on you can do this (at least in sql server but i think it's ansi sql):

```
  SELECT RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(11),ID),2)
```

or how i it's also possible on SQL Server:

```
  SELECT RIGHT(CONCAT('0',CAST(ID AS NVARCHAR(11))),2)
```

Comment: NVARCHAR(11) because INT can be between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647 ... for tinyint use 3, for smallint 6, for bigint 20. Refers to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-at/library/ms187745(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: Hi why Right Concat and not Left

Comment: let's do it for ID 1: CONCAT 0 and 1 is 01 -> right 2 gets `01`. For ID 21: CONAT 0 and 21 gets 021 -> right 2 gets `21`. but maybe i didn't get what you really want!?

Comment: also is my sign correct (>) or should i use this instead (<)